I can't set max temperature using `lm-sensors`
When I try to update lm-sensors settings:
chip "coretemp-isa-0000"
    compute temp1 99,100
    compute temp2 100,99
    compute temp3 @-2,@-1
    compute temp4 @-1,@-2

after service lm-sensors restart I get that the crit and high temperature are always the same:
$ sensors
asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:     2400 RPM

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:           8.41 V  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +99.0°C  (high = +99.0°C, crit = +99.0°C)
Core 0:       +100.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +42.0°C  (high = +98.0°C, crit = +98.0°C)
Core 2:        +44.0°C  (high = +99.0°C, crit = +99.0°C)
Core 3:        +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

nvme-pci-e100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +31.9°C  (low  =  -5.2°C, high = +79.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +46.0°C  

Is it a bug of lm-sensors? If I cannot properly (I mean separately for high and crit) set temperature by lm-sensors, how to set it using /proc or /sys interface directly?
My computer is an ASUS laptop with 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz.
$ uname -a
Linux victor 6.8.0-31-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Apr 20 00:40:06 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
